# Convert a date array to milliseconds array filled with same values based on range using range() and array_fill_keys()

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$result =[
  "2019-03-01" => ["val"=>10]
  "2019-03-13" => ["val"=>20]
  "2019-03-22" => ["val"=>30]
  "2020-03-15" => ["val"=>40] 
];
```

I need to convert it to milliseconds and fill with same value for the date ranges using range() and array_fill_keys function
for example

```
date         milliseconds  value
2019-03-01  1551427200000             10
2019-03-02                  10
2019-03-03                  10 
.
.
.
2019-03-12                  10 
2019-03-13                  20
.
.
 2019-03-21                 20
 2019-03-22                 30
```

How do i create an array with milliseconds filled with values?

I have tried this:

```
$result =[   "2019-03-01" => ["val"=>10],   "2019-03-13" => ["val"=>20],   "2019-03-22" => ["val"=>30],   "2020-03-15" => ["val"=>40]  ]; 
    $timestamp = [];
    
    $i=0;
    
    $dates=[]; $dates=array_keys($result); while ($i<count($dates)-1){
        
        $tempdate1 = new DateTime($dates[$i]);
        $date1 = new DateTime($dates[$i++]);
        $date2 = new DateTime($dates[$i]);
        $days  = $date2->diff($date1)->format('%a');
         $timestamp[$date1->format('Y-m-d')] =$result[$tempdate1->format('Y-m-d')];   for ($x = 0; $x <= $days-1; $x++) {
          $temp_date=$date1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d');
            
             $timestamp[$temp_date] =$result[$tempdate1->format('Y-m-d')];
        } }
    
    print_r($timestamp);
```

But i would like to have it as a timestamp array and would like to use range() and array_fill_keys?

Comment: What are you supposed to derive the milliseconds from?

Comment: from the dates 2019-03-01 until 2020-03-15

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get from string to timestamp:

```
<?php

$t = new DateTime('2019-03-01');
$n = $t->getTimestamp() * 1000;

var_dump($n === 1551398400000);
```

https://php.net/datetime.gettimestamp